# Any alternatives of using 'Despite..' or 'In spite..' or 'Having worked..' in my context?

Tags: word-choice

I don't want to use words like despite, in spite and Having worked on for the below sentence. It looks clumsy and repeated(if I use Having worked on..) to me. Please let me know about any suggestion.

> Despite of being an embedded and desktop application developer I have also worked on web technologies and Photoshop designs both as a hobby and as a profession.

Comment: I would've loved to help, but unfortunately one of the website's rules is that we don't do proofreading here.

Comment: As Cookie Monster said, *"Me want cookie!"*.  No, wait, that's the other one.  Anyway, as he said, please edit your question to indicate what might be confusing or difficult in this sentence, and we can help with that particular vocabulary or grammar.

Comment: "Despite of" -> "In addition to".

Answer (score 2):

Laugh's suggestion of "in addition" to is a good way to change this from a negative to a positive association.

> **In addition to** being a professional ballet dancer and an accomplished television chef, he is also a virtuoso pianist.

Comment: Is there a really sound reason to use "in addition to" as well as "being" at all? "A professional ballet dancer and an accomplished television chef, he is also a virtuoso pianist."

Comment: @Rompey, you can write it that way but occasionally it can be confusing, since the listener might assume you are talking about three different people, skip over the "also", and have to re-read to make sure what you meant to say.  It's like the [joke about the Oxford comma](https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2014-01/enhanced/webdr03/15/13/enhanced-buzz-19599-1389811749-10.jpg?downsize=715:*&output-format=auto&output-quality=auto) -- sometimes it's better to add a few extra words to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Starting with "in addition to being", "also" may seem redundant, may it not? But starting it the way I suggested, "also" is sorely needed. Thanks for responding readily to my comment, though.

Comment: @Rompey  Yes, the second "also" is redundant.  A good editor would have crossed it out.   Many people will leave it in as extra emphasis.

Answer (score -3):

Despite of being an embedded and desktop application developer I have also worked on web technologies and Photoshop designs both as a hobby and as a profession.

should read

Despite being an embedded and desktop application developer, I have also worked on web technologies and Photoshop designs, both as a hobbyist and as a professional.

although the sentence construction is somewhat clumsy, even in that format.